# PHP utf-8 read file by char

Tags: php, utf-8

I have some serious problem dealing with files in php with utf-8 encoding. I need to read a file char by char or possibly line by line, with fixed small chunks.
I tried to use **fgetc** and **fgets** but characters encoded in utf8 are split in a few "*chars*" instead of only one. I'm trying to find a solution, it could be even a small "*string*" containing only the character in Unicode but it must be read from file properly.

Pseudo code I would like to use:

```
while ( ($c == read_utf8_char($file)) != false ) {
    if ($c == 'ó') do_something();
}
```

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function mb_str_split($string) { 
    return preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $string ); 
} 

$chars = mb_str_split($file);

foreach ($chars as $c) {
    if ($c == 'ó') do_something();
}
```

*~ Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php#99851*

Comment: But what about performance? If I have a very large file and I would like small memory footprint?

Comment: Regex actually works very good with large files, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I used your code and applied it to my framework. It works pretty well but it omits line breaks. How to deal with '\n' or '\r\n' characters?

Comment: Maybe you could just use the file() function and then use this function over each specific line?

Comment: Hmm.. Actually the code you have posted works with newlines. It was my mistake. Instead of $c == "\n" I did $c == '\n'. Sorry for that ;) I figured it out after I rewrote all my reading code. Thanks!